# Django fragment caching in layout page keyed by page url

Tags: django

I am trying to cache everything by page url and user id
in a layout page (base.html), the idea is the url changes, get the correct page html for that page, and if the user signs in, cache by user

Right now the below caches the first page, and if i click on a url in the menu, the url changes but the html returned is from the first page loaded

How do i break the cache?

```
{% cache 300 request.build_absolute_uri request.user %}
<html>
 {% block content %} {% endblock %}
</html>   
{% endcache %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you need to have `{% load cached %}` right at the top or this will not work.

The first parameter to the cache template tag is the timeout and the second one is the name. Thus your code needs to be changed as follows:

```
{% cache 300 FULL_PAGE request.build_absolute_uri request.user %}
```

This will solve the issue you have run into. However permit me to try to persuade you against using this caching strategy. If you have 1000 users and each of them visit 5 pages and each page is 10kb you are using up 5MB of your cache. And those objects in the cache have a very short lifetime so churning will be the order of the day.